# Stat issue - comparing list against itself

Tags: c#, statistics, computer-science

This one is for you CompSci or stats people. Can you please tell me, if theList contains 72,786 "things," what the value of compareCount will be at the end of the loops? I'm thinking it's 72,786^2-1 but it's been soo long since this old brain worked like that. Much obliged for your time and assistance!

```
List<thing> theList = new List<thing>();//list contains 73,786 "things"
    private void compare()
    {
        int compareCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < theList.Count-1; i++)
        {
            for(int comp = i + 1; comp < theList.Count; comp++)
            {
                compare(theList[i], theList[comp]);
                compareCount++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you run it to find out?

Comment: I am - I'm trying to figure out when it will be done and what memory issues I might be expecting based on what's happening so far. I'm about 2% complete if list.Count^2-1 is correct. If that's the right number, then I have an ETC of slightly less than 30 days at 99% CPU load.

Comment: If this is just a math question, then it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.  You should post it on [math stack exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Intended as a possible two-parter, but no sense in asking the second part until I know the first part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compareCount in your code will have the value `(72786^2 - 72786) / 2 = 2648864505`. I've confirmed that by running it. As it is written now, there is no need to have the call `compare(theList[i], theList[comp])` in the inner loop (as it doesn't influence the count in any way).

Here's how I remember the `(n^2 - n)/2` formula: a round robin tournament with `n` players, each of them meeting all other players exactly once.

The match plan is a square with `n` rows and columns (`n * n = n^2` combinations). Since a player doesn't play against himself the `n` matches on the diagonal from upper left to lower right must be subtracted (`n^2 - n`matches left now). Pairings of player `A` against player `B` in the triangle above the diagonal are the same as pairings of `B` against `A` in the triangle below (there are `(n^2 - n)/2` of such pairings). Subtracting this number from `n^2 - n` gives the final result of `(n^2 - n)/2` possible matches.

Comment: MUCH appreciated! I'm a ditz in that I didn't think of running it without the actual comparison (which takes all the time). Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm dumping the results to files and I've only accounted for five numeric digits in the filename, which means I'll throw an exception on filename before I'm done. I'm already 3 days into this but starting over now is a lot better than doing it in two weeks. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Never mind :) Btw, next time use an uint or long for the `compareCount` as an int will overflow.

Comment: Just want you to know - thanks to your help I realized I not only needed to stop/rebuild/restart but also reduce my sampling size to get a realistic run time. I'm down to 1.61Billion combinations and have plenty of room to save them. You saved me days of wasted time.

Comment: Glad, I could help you :)